# List out of bounds error

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Here my code for the extension controller and I am geeting the error above

I there anything that I need to do

Comment: Its not giving the line number its just throwing an exception(I think so) and the debug log is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
name=:lqc.LQ_Agreement__c
```

Should be

```
Id=:lqc.LQ_Agreement__c
```

Since lookup fields store ID's, not names.

Comment: And same with "where name=:lqa[0].Opportunity__c", obviously.

Answer (score 2):

From the code listed I'd say the problem is with this line:

`o=[select name,Id,RecordTypeID from Opportunity where name=:lqa[0].Opportunity__c];`

You don't check the size of lqa until after that line, yet you index into the list of records with [0] there. If the list is empty then the 0 would be out of bounds. Your debug log should show how many records are returned by the query.

Comment: Is there any problem with the lqa query as there are no records that are being retreived.

Comment: Not that I can see, be sure that a record ID is being passed in the URL, and then make sure that the field `LQ_Agreement__c` on the `LQ_Contract__c` record actually has a valid value.

Comment: On a related note, in the event that you're trying to display over 1000 records, Visualforce will choke and display this error as well (or I think I remember seeing it anyway).

In any case, it's usually a good practice to add LIMIT x to the end of any SOQL query, even if it's literally 50000000. In your case you could say LIMIT 1, but there's really no need since any "SELECT WHERE primary key =" type queries will return 1 or 0 results.